# Player already guessed the number

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm having difficulties telling the player that the player already guessed the number.

This is my code:

```
import random

number = random.randint (1, 100)
guess = int(input("\nCan you guess the number?\n\n"))

guessing = 1

def get_guess(already_guessed):
    guess = input()
    if guess in already_guessed:
        print("You already guessed that number.")
    else:
        return guess

while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")
    if guess == number:
        break

    guess = get_guess(input("Try again.\n\n"))
```

Comment: You never update your `already_guessed` variable

Comment: Ok you have to rewrite your code, break it into smaller parts, there are several errors (too many `input()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never updating your `already_guessed` variable you could add it to your `get_guess` function. And also you have too many `input`. Try that:

```
import random

number = random.randint (1, 100)
guess = int(input("\nCan you guess the number?\n\n"))

already_guessed = []

def get_guess(already_guessed):
    if guess in already_guessed:
        print("You already guessed that number.")
    else:
        already_guessed.append(guess)
    return already_guessed


while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")
    if guess == number:
        break

    guess = int(input("Try again.\n\n"))
    already_guessed = get_guess(already_guessed)
```

Comment: Thanks every one for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't maintain a list of guesses seen, but you try to use it.

You pass input in place of the **already_guessed** list at the end.

Your input statement flow is not consistent with game play.

Your termination doesn't tell the player that s/he won, and you use a redundant **break** statement.

```
import random

number = random.randint (1, 100)
guess = int(input("\nCan you guess the number?\n\n"))

guessing = 1
seen = []

def get_guess(already_guessed):
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess?"))
    if guess in already_guessed:
        print("You already guessed that number.")
    else:
        return guess

while guess != number:
    seen.append(guess)
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")
    guess = get_guess(seen)

print "You win!"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the following is observed when I run it.

Let's say the secret number is 90.
1. The user input 99.
2. The message displayed is correct the first time. "Your guess is too high."
3. The user input 99 again.
4. The message "Your guess is too low" is displayed and not "Your guess is too high"

I can't figure out why it doesn't display "Your guess is too high" again. Could you help?

Comment: Yes -- I didn't fix that portion of your logic.  If the guess is a repeat, you return nothing, which defaults to "None".  This causes the comparison to come back as too low.  Rather, you should put a loop into **get_guess** to keep asking until you get a valid guess.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. If guess is a repeat, the returned value is none so else is returning 0 which is lower than any number.